# What is the regex expression for matching the text between "[[" and "]]"?

Tags: c#, regex, ckeditor

What is the regex expression for matching the text between "[[" and "]]"?

for eg:

```
[[* repeat i by "4" until [[%arrAccountDetails.Count%]] *]]

[[*endrepeat*]]

[[* if expr=[[%event.RemainingAccountCount%]] != "" *]]

[[*endif*]]
```

I am writing a custom code between "[[" and "]]" which need to treat as server side code.

Thanks and Regards
Venkatesh G

Comment: If you have nested brackets dont use regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
\[\[([^]]*)\]\]
```

now the only captured group has what you want.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q4SjVN/1)

Comment: Thank you heemayl.

Comment: But I am getting the error as "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token ". 
I am using this code in creditor's config.protectedSource.push(\[\[([^]]*)\]\]) to indentify the my code and treat as server side code.

Comment: Yes the error is gone. And I think the regex is working correctly.

Comment: But it seems that the CKEditor is not identifying this. I need to keep the code inserted between table rows HTML tags

Comment: @VenkateshG I'm not familiar with that, sorry. As you can see in the Demo that this is working perfectly.

Comment: Yes heemayl, In demo it is working correctly for php but not for javascript